# Tag excerpts from 'obligatory' tags on per-site metas do not appear in the 'all tags' page?

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, per-site-meta, tag-wiki-excerpt

Tag excerpts from 'obligatory' tags (e.g. [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)) and 'moderation' tags (e.g. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)) on **per-site metas** do not appear in the [all tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) page. However, in Meta Stack Exchange they do (see picture below).

[image]

I have used Cross Validated SE and GIS SE as examples. Notice that excerpts for such tags do exist (for example, [discussion] --> [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) and [here](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion), respectively).

This happens probably because while in Meta SE the excerpts have a history (were edited at least once) on the per-site metas which I cited as examples still have the system's default excerpt.

**Nonetheless**, I think we should take advantage that there are excerpts for such tags an enable them in the 'all tags' page.